# Same user login on Different wordpress domains with different databases

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, authentication, content-management-system

We have two different wordpress domains with different databases, How to code for same user login on bothe the sites. We have to use different databases not one.
ie.
   www.site1.com                   DB1
   www.site2.com                   DB2

Comment: Maybe there is a Wordpress plugin for OpenID authentication? Might be worth looking into.

Comment: please describe the method.

Comment: I can't; I have never used it. Google `wordpress openid`

Comment: Not sure I follow. Is the first hit for that query (the one on wordpress.com) not helpful? Why?

Comment: Basically I dont want to use any third party user authentication, I want to save all the data to one of my WP site Database. @Pekka웃

Comment: Hmm, not sure whether this is possible. Have you considered synchronizing the two databases frequently?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and setup the wordpress network solution to achieve this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

alternatively there is a third party method if this does not achieve what you want.

https://managewp.com/

there is a premium plugin by wpmu that can do this as well

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-user-synchronization/

Comment: I know about the Wordpress network, But It work with same databse.
and we have to use different databases as suggested by my client.